# C program compiles but does not run

Tags: c

I am working on a Word Search program in C. The program should take the files (data1, data2, data3) which contain word searches as input and output the searches with only the solved words ( which are contained in solution1, solution2, solution3). The program compiles fine but when I attempt to run it, nothing happens. My code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 50

/*Function Prototypes*/
void get_Array(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], int *size);
void get_Words(char words[MAX][MAX], int *num_words);
void print_Array(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], int size);
void print_Words(char words[MAX][MAX]);
int word_Search(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], char current_word[MAX], int dir, int pos, int row, int col, char solved[MAX][MAX], int size);
void solve_puzzle(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], char solved[MAX][MAX], char words[MAX][MAX], int size, int num_words);
void initialize_Array(char array[MAX][MAX], int size);

int main()
{
    char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX];
    char solved[MAX][MAX];
    char words[MAX][MAX];

    int size = 0;
    int num_words = 0;
    int a;

    /*Get the input from stdin*/
    get_Array(word_Puzzle, &size);
    get_Words(words, &num_words);
    initialize_Array(solved, size);

    /*Solve the puzzle*/
    solve_puzzle(word_Puzzle, solved, words, size, num_words);

    /*Finally, Print it!*/
    print_Array(solved, size);

    stdin = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");

    printf("Enter something:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n",a);

    return 0;
}

void get_Array(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], int *size)
{
    char current_char = 'a';
    int row, col, temp = 0;

    /*Get the first line, setting the size of the array.*/
    while(current_char != '\n')
    {
        current_char = getchar();
        if(current_char != '\n' && current_char != ' ')
        {
            word_Puzzle[0][temp] = current_char;
            temp++;
        }
    }

    /* Assign size the value of the temp variable */
    *size = temp;

    /* temp is now the length of the array, lets fill the rest in. */
    for(row = 1; row < temp; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < temp; col++)
        {
            word_Puzzle[row][col] = getchar();
            /*Do another getchar to skip the space*/
            getchar();
        }
        /*Do a getchar to skip the newline character*/
        getchar();
    }
}

void get_Words(char words[MAX][MAX], int *num_words)
{
    char current_word[MAX + 1];
    char *scanned_word = current_word;
    int temp = 0, pos = 0;

    do {
        /*Take in the word*/
        scanned_word = fgets(current_word, 50, stdin);

        if(scanned_word == NULL)
            break;

        strcpy(words[pos], scanned_word);
        pos++;
        temp++;
    }while(current_word != NULL);

    *num_words = temp;
}

void print_Array(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], int size)
{
    int row, col;

    for(row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for(col=0; col < size; col++)
        {
            printf("%c ", word_Puzzle[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_Words(char words[MAX][MAX])
{
    int row;

    for(row = 0; row < MAX + 1; row++)
    {
        printf("%s", words[row]);
    }
}

int word_Search(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX], char current_word[MAX], int dir,    int pos, int row, int col, char solved[MAX][MAX], int size)
{
    /*End of word, return 1!*/
    if (current_word[pos] == '\n' || current_word[pos] == '\0')
        return 1;

    /*If its out of bounds, return 0.*/
    if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= size || col >= size)
        return 0;


    /*Switch the direction of the search, that way it only goes the direction
    its looking.*/
    switch(dir)
    {
        /*Search L2R, row+0, col+1*/
        case 0:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row, col+1, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search R2L, row+0, col-1*/
        case 1:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row, col-1, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search B2T, row-1, col+0*/
        case 2:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row-1, col, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search T2B, row+1, col+0*/
        case 3:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row+1, col, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search ULD, row-1, col-1*/
        case 4:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row-1, col-1, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search URD, row-1, col+1*/
        case 5:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row-1, col+1, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search BLD, row+1, col-1*/
        case 6:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row+1, col-1, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;

        /*Search BRD, row+1, col+1*/
        case 7:
            if(current_word[pos] == word_Puzzle[row][col])
            {
                if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, dir, pos+1, row+1, col+1, solved, size))
                {
                    solved[row][col] = word_Puzzle[row][col];
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void solve_puzzle(char word_Puzzle[MAX][MAX],char solved[MAX][MAX], char words[MAX][MAX], int size, int num_words)
{
    char current_word[MAX + 1];
    int found = 0;
    int word, r, c, d;

    /*Go through each word in the word array...*/
    for(word = 0; word < num_words; word++)
    {
        strcpy(current_word, words[word]);
        found = 0;

        /*...and search each row...*/
        for(r = 0; r < size; r++)
        {
            /*...each column...*/
            for(c = 0; c < size; c++)
            {
                /*...and each direction till its found, and if it is, BREAK!*/
                for(d = 0; d < 8; d++)
                {
                    if(word_Search(word_Puzzle, current_word, d, 0, r, c, solved, size))
                    {
                        found = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(found)
                    break;
            }
            if(found)
                break;
        }
    }
}

/*Set all the cells in the solved array for cleanliness.*/
void initialize_Array(char array[MAX][MAX], int size)
{
    int row, col;

    for(row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            array[row][col] = ' ';
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Did you run it in gdb or a debugger, or put in `printf` statements to see how far it's getting and where it's spinning?  Sometimes I go and put just `printf("1\n");`, `printf("2\n");`,  etc... on various lines real quick and see what number it stops at and then add, remove or move print statements until I figure out where the problem is.  Debugger is better if available but more learning overhead. But you have to be able to narrow it down. Will help to get more answers here if you can narrow it to a specific problem area instead of having everyone master all your code.

Comment: I'd like to point out that's a lot of code to expect people to troubleshoot for free when you haven't reduced the scope of the problem and isolated it to a specific technical issue.  Further your bracing style takes a long program and makes it much harder to read in a small window because it requires so much scrolling and less code can be seen as once.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems I think could be breaking your code:

In the `get_Array` method, in the second for loop, the way it is right now it expects an input like this:

```
A space B space C space \n
```

Notice that last space? I'm not sure that is what you intended. Just removing the last `getchar();` might do it.

Also important noting that `fgets()` will also include the NewLine ate the end of the string, so if you are separating the words like `'word\word\n'` this might be an issue.